# Custom error handler for screenshots in Python-Behave

Tags: python, selenium, bdd, python-behave

I created a custom error handler to handle screenshots when fail

```
#error_handler.py

def screenshot_handler(func):
    def func_wrapper(self):
        try:
            return func(self)
        except Exception as e:
            print("screenshot") 
            return func(self)
    return func_wrapper
```

---

```
#page.py

@screenshot_handler
def assert_login(self,a):
    self.find_element(*DashboardPageLocators.AUTOREFRESH_BUTTON)
    return True
```

---

```
#steps.py
"""
i forced this to fail
"""

@then('map should display')
def step_impl(context):
    page = LoginPage(context)
    page.assert_login()
```

---

I want to grab the step argument 'map should display' so I create the filename out of it. The most obvious option is to copy the string, but that would be inefficient, is there a behave function that i could call to do handle this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do this in the `after_step` function of environments.py:

```
def after_step(context, step):
    if step.status == 'failed':
        step_str = step.name
        # Take screen shot and upload to s3
```

You get immediate access to the test status and step name, and you don't have to include your own error handling decorators.

The `step` variable has a number of nifty things in it:

```
(Pdb) pp(dir(step))

['__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__',
 '__le__',
 '__lt__',
 '__module__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__weakref__',
 'duration',
 'error_message',
 'exc_traceback',
 'exception',
 'filename',
 'keyword',
 'line',
 'location',
 'name',
 'replay',
 'reset',
 'run',
 'set_values',
 'status',
 'step_type',
 'store_exception_context',
 'table',
 'text',
 'type']
```

The step string is simply `test.name`

Comment: how about the step string how do i access that

Comment: @teddybear123 Updated the answer